# How to add 24 more prime numbers in the output and have it arranged from lowest to highest?

Tags: java

i'm currently being asked to create a machine code that will generate multiple distinct random prime numbers and have it's output be displayed from highest prime number to lowest

i'm already done doing a the isPrime method the output only gives me 1 random prime number.

```
package isPrime.isPrime;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Primusnumberus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0;
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;

        while (!isPrime(num)) {          
            num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(num);  
    }


    private static boolean isPrime(int inputNum){
        if (inputNum <= 3 || inputNum % 2 == 0) 
            return inputNum == 2 || inputNum == 3; 
        int divisor = 3;
        while ((divisor <= Math.sqrt(inputNum)) && (inputNum % divisor != 0)) 
            divisor += 2; 
        return inputNum % divisor != 0; 
    }
}
```

I expect the output of 
(println)
731
11
971
53
17 and so fort

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is `isPrime` method doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a loop and add those random prime numbers to a list. Then sort the list and print it at the end like below,

```
package isPrime.isPrime;
import java.util.*;

public class Primusnumberus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 0;
        int numberCount = 24;
        int counter = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (counter < numberCount) {
            num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
            while (!isPrime(num)) {
                num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
            }
            if (!primeList.contains(num)) {
                primeList.add(num);
                counter ++;
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(primeList);
        System.out.println(primeList);
    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int inputNum){
        if (inputNum <= 3 || inputNum % 2 == 0)
            return inputNum == 2 || inputNum == 3;
        int divisor = 3;
        while ((divisor <= Math.sqrt(inputNum)) && (inputNum % divisor != 0))
            divisor += 2;
        return inputNum % divisor != 0;
    }
}
```

I have just updated your code to your requirement. But this won't be a good method to get random prime numbers since it might take some time when the number count increases.

Answer (score 2):

You have to generate the primes in a loop for example

```
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){ // If you do not want 25 Primes change it here
    num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;

    while (!isPrime(num)) {          
        num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Btw.: generating them using Random may result in a very long execution time of your program.
If you just need primes up to 1001 I would recommend generating them all and then just selecting them at random. (using a List for example)

Comment: i tried this but it generated 25 619(same prime number 25 times)